# How to check convexity?

Tags: convex-analysis

How can I know the function $$f(x,y)=\frac{y^2}{xy+1}$$ with $x>0$,$y>0$ is convex or not?

Comment: Have you looked at the Hessian matrix? If it is positive semidefinite, $f$ is convex.

Comment: I checked the Hessian matrix, but unfortunately it is indefinite.

Comment: So the two eigenvalues of the Hessian have opposite signs, meaning one eigenvalue is negative. The function will be concave in the direction of the corresponding eigenspace.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think it is a good suggestion.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Consider $y=x$ then we have $\displaystyle g(x)=\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}=1-\frac 1{x^2+1}$

The second derivative of this is $g''(x)=\frac{2-6x^2}{(1+x^2)^3}$
and will change sign around $x=\frac 1{\sqrt{3}}$ so that $g$ is convex in $(0,\frac 1{\sqrt{3}})$ and concave in $(\frac 1{\sqrt{3}},\infty)$.

Your function is clearly not convex nor concave on $(\mathbb{R^{+*}})^2$ but you could search more restricted sets if needed...

Here is a picture (from below) of your function (convex near $y=0$ and concave when $y$ becomes larger at least in the x=y direction, in the x=-y direction it looks convex...) :

[image: picture]

Comment: What is the motivation for setting $y = x$ ?

Comment: Simplify the problem to disprove convexity (it is a trick and proving complexity may require something like a Hessian for derivable functions).

Comment: yeah but you already know the answer about the convexity in advance right. Is there anyway to do this in an objective manner ?

Comment: In fact I didn't know it was convex or not and set $y=x$ to get some intuition. The Hessian way proposed in the comments and by robjohn is [the way to go for two variables or more for a differentiable real function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test#The_test).

Answer (score 14):

The Hessian of $\frac{y^2}{1+xy}$ is
$$
H
=
\frac1{(1+xy)^3}\begin{bmatrix}
2y^4&-y^2(3+xy)\\[12pt]
-y^2(3+xy)&2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
u&v
\end{bmatrix}
H
\begin{bmatrix}
u\\v
\end{bmatrix}
=\frac2{(1+xy)^3}(v-uy^2)^2-\frac1{(1+xy)^2}uvy^2
$$
Setting $\begin{bmatrix}u&v\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&y^2\end{bmatrix}$ gives
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&y^2
\end{bmatrix}
H
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\y^2
\end{bmatrix}
=-\frac{y^4}{(1+xy)^2}
$$
so $\frac{y^2}{1+xy}$ is not convex as long as $y\ne0$.

Comment: What is the motivation for setting [$u$    $v$]  =  [$1$     $y^2$] ?

Comment: We want to find a point which gives a negative value. $\frac2{(1+xy)^3}(v-uy^2)^2-\frac1{(1+xy)^2}uvy^2=-\frac{y^4}{(1+xy)^2}$ at $\begin{bmatrix}u&v\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&y^2\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 9):

The book "Convex Optimization" by Boyd, available free online [here](http://www.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf), describes methods to check.

The standard definition is if f(θx + (1 − θ)y) ≤ θf(x) + (1 − θ)f(y) for 0≤θ≤1 and the domain of x,y is also convex.

So if you could prove that for your function, you would know it's convex.

The Hessian being positive semi-definite, as mentioned in comments, would also show that the function is convex.

See page 67 of the book for more.

Comment: Your answer is not useful. I think checking the eigenvalue of the Hessian matrix maybe a good approach.

Comment: It is a very good book on the subject if you wish to go deeper than simple calculus.

Comment: Using the standard definition is almost always completely useless.  The only time it is useful is if you have a function which is not continuous in its second derivative (or it doesn't exist) then you can rule out it is convex if you can numerically find a counter-example simply by randomly evaluating SEVERAL points.  But this isn't generally practical or fun, nor can it ever prove a function IS convex, only that it isn't if you happen to find a counter-example.

Comment: @Squirtle, it can absolutely prove a function is convex: if you show a function satisfies that condition, it is convex. As a basic example, let f(x)=5x and you will see that that condition is always an equality. Therefore f(x)=5x is convex everywhere.